# Calculating deflection for a home built trailer

Tags: mechanical-engineering, steel, design

I am designing a 4'x12' trailer frame.  8' of it will support weight, the balance will be the tongue.  My area of concern is bending at the ends of the long supports.  There will be a wheel assembly located 4' from the frames end that will support all but the tongue weight of 100 -120 lbs.  I plan to use commercial steel tubing so the moment of inertia ($I$) and Section Modulus ($Z$) are known quantities.

What I need is a formula that is suited to this design - ie. something that will tell me how much the frame might bend under load.  I have some knowledge of simple design as well as an AISC and Machinery's handbooks

---

Its going to be a 4' x 8' with a 4' tongue, the tongue weight should be 50 to 80 lbs. I'm designing it to keep the weight below 900 lbs.  I want it to have 15" wheels.   I'm using components for a design weight of 2000 lbs. and plan on using axle-less wheel hubs.  There will be a close to a uniform load spaced over the wheels.  The wheel assembly will be off center to improve tracking.

I'm looking for a suitable "Beam Diagram" to ensure I stay within a reasonable deflection.   I have seen them designed with 2" x 2", and 2" x 3" tubing.

Comment: Do a google search for trailer plans and find one that best fits your needs.  No need to completely design something yourself when plenty of others have already done it.

Comment: Can you add a sketch of your basic design?  It doesn't need to be perfect, but it will help to give users a better sense of the dimensions and design.

Comment: Also try [Autodesk Force Effect](https://forceeffect.autodesk.com/index.html) (free) to solve various static problems.

Comment: Can you give us a diagram of the locations and magnitudes of the moments, forces, and supports?

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar design need. Found a free software tool called Beamboy2.2  With the engineering data you have this simple piece of software can be a great testbed for your solutions.

The software accommodates cantilever beam setup so you can test specifically for the deflection of the steel based on your specific loading conditions.

The link I downloaded from is http://www.geocities.ws/richgetze/beamb22.zip

Basically I set up a beam model that goes from hitch to end of frame. Representing one support rail so halve your loads. I design at 2.5 times actual loads to accommodate the effects of bumps and dips. 2.5 is what the better commercial shops use.

I use $\ell/300$ as my deflection limit measured from the support at the axle to the end of the frame.

I suppose for liability I should wave and scream that after you use this to see what works and what you want to build you ***must*** take it to a real live engineer. I am not one. Nor is this software. But the math seems accurate and I'm sure you'll find it useful.

Comment: Thanks for this! I wish that I had this program when I was going through mechanics of materials!